# How to get empty result set in MySQL query with aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

```
select d.name as 'name', sum(r.distance) as 'sum_distance'
from driver d
       inner join ride r on r.driver_id = d.id
where r.end_time2 > '2018-09-25'
  and r.start_time2 < '2018-09-26';
```

If there're no rides between the specified dates this query results in

```
| name | sum_distance |
| ---- | ------------ |
| null |     null     |
```

But I want it to return an empty set. I think it's because of using an aggregate function like `sum`, `avg`, `max` in the query. `ride` - `driver` is Many-to-One relation. I tried to modify the query in different ways but it still doesn't return an empty set. For example:

```
select d.name as 'name', sum(r.distance) as 'sum_distance'
from driver d
       inner join ride r on r.driver_id = d.id
where r.end_time2 > '2018-09-25'
  and r.start_time2 < '2018-09-26'
  and d.name IS NOT NULL;
```

How to fix this MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To consider all of the "riders", despite having no distance travelled, you need to use `Left Join` with the `driver` table as your first table.
- Now, to calculate the total distance travelled by them, use [Sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) with [Ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function to return 0 distance travelled instead of `null`. Due to left join, distance value will come up as `null` if there is no matching row found in the second table `ride`.
- Also, you should use `Group By` when using aggregate functions like `Sum`.

Try the following:

```
select d.name as 'name', 
       sum(ifnull(r.distance,0)) as 'sum_distance'
from driver d
left join ride r on r.driver_id = d.id
where r.end_time2 > '2018-09-25'
  and r.start_time2 < '2018-09-26' 
group By d.name
```

Comment: `left join` didn't help (I find this strange), but `group by` worked. thank you!

Comment: @naXa newer MySQL versions are stricter regarding usage of aggregations functions and group by. Read up on `only_full_group_by`. Without using group by, the query wont be ANSI SQL compliant